# Javascript Split/Join Or Replace spaces globally

Tags: javascript, html

I am running outta my mind now, can someone please explain what is happening here:

[image: Screenshot]

Why's the same JS function producing different results?

Here's the actual HTML:

```
<input id="xamount" data-pr-xamount="1" value="R 5 700,00" placeholder="Enter Amount" style="width: 88%;" class="valid" type="text">
```

Comment: Could you provide respective HTML?

Comment: Might not be a regular space between the `5` and the `700`, so when you `split(' ')` you will get only 2 items.

Comment: @AndrewLi I've added the HTML

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those spaces may not be traditional spaces, try splitting on actual white-space:

```
/\s+/
```

In your case:

```
$('[data-pr-xamount="1"]').last().val().split(/\s+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be a character different than a space between 5 and 7.